# Measure Render-To-Texture Performance in OpenGL ES 2.0

Tags: c++, c, performance, opengl-es, render-to-texture

Basically, I'm doing some sort of image processing using a screen-sized rectangle made of two triangles and a fragment shader, which is doing the whole processing stuff. The actual effect is something like an animation as it depends on a uniform variable, called `current_frame`.

I'm very much interested in measuring the performance in terms of "MPix/s". What I do is something like that:

```
/* Setup all necessary stuff, including:                 */
/* - getting the location of the `current_frame` uniform */
/* - creating an FBO, adding a color attachment          */
/*   and setting it as the current one                   */

double current_frame = 0;
double step = 1.0f / NUMBER_OF_ITERATIONS;

tic(); /* Start counting the time */

for (i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_ITERATIONS; i++)
{
    glUniform1f(current_frame_handle, current_frame);
    current_frame += step;
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, NUMBER_OF_INDICES);
    glFinish();
}

double elapsed_time = tac(); /* Get elapsed time in seconds */

/* Calculate achieved pixels per second */
double pps = (OUT_WIDTH * OUT_HEIGHT * NUMBER_OF_ITERATIONS) / elapsed_time;

/* Sanity check by using reading the output into a buffer */
/* using glReadPixels and saving this buffer into a file  */
```

As far as theory goes, is there anything wrong with my concept?

Also, I've got the impression that `glFinish()` on mobile hardware doesn't necessarily wait for previous render calls and may do some optimizations.

Of course, I can always *force* it by doing `glReadPixels()` after each draw, but that would be quite slow so that this wouldn't really help.

Could you advise me as to whether my testing scenario is sensible and whether there is something more that can be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concerning speed, using `glDrawArrays()` still duplicates the shared vertices.

> glDrawElements() is the solution to reduce the number of vertices in
>   the array, so it allows transferring less data to OpenGL.

http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_vertexarray.html

Just throwing that in there to help speed up your results. As far as your timing concept, it looks fine to me. Are you getting results similar to what you had hoped?

Comment: Thanks! It's good to know that. Still, it's only 6 vertices per frame. Generally, I'm getting some rather absurdly high results. Something like 1 sec for 10,000 iterations on a 256x256 texture (i.e. around 650Mpix/s), where the shader just copies the texture. And that's on a SGX530. I'm really puzzled.

Comment: IDK man, that's a lot of pixels haha. Cut the iterations in half and see if it cuts your elapsed time by roughly half. If its still close to the same time, your problem might be GL state, but I doubt it

Comment: Well, the theoretical fill rate of the SGX530 is around 500-1000 Mpix/s. Still, reading the texture should slow it down quite a bit. And, I've already tried changing the parameters. For a 4x bigger image (512x512) it takes 4x more time to do the same count of iterations so it seems to be linear. Still, it doesn't make me feel more confident in my measurements.

Comment: *reading the texture*? You're expecting slower results? I don't see the code here reading textures

Comment: That happens in the shader of course. Something like `gl_Color = texture2D(texture, tex_coords);`

Answer (score 0):

I would precalculate all possible frames, and then use glEnableClientState() and glTexCoordPointer() to change which part of the existing texture is drawn in each frame.

Comment: This is not OpenGL ES 2.0 related however.